# Pandas Split on '. '

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'foo':['abc','2. abc','3. abc']})
df

 foo
   abc
2. abc
3. abc
```

I'd like to split on '. ' to produce this:

```
foo   bar
      abc
1     abc
2     abc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function:

```
In [163]: df.foo.str.extract(r'(?P<foo>\d*)[\.\s]*(?P<bar>.*)', expand=True)
Out[163]:
  foo  bar
0      abc
1   2  abc
2   3  abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), but then you need swap values if `mask` is `True` by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `''` column `foo`:

```
df1 = (df.foo.str.split('. ', expand=True))
df1.columns = ['foo','bar']

print (df1)
   foo   bar
0  abc  None
1    2   abc
2    3   abc

mask = df1.bar.isnull()
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: bar, dtype: bool

df1['foo'], df1['bar'] = np.where(mask, df1['bar'], df1['foo']), 
                         np.where(mask, df1['foo'], df1['bar'] )

df1.foo.fillna('', inplace=True)

print (df1)
  foo  bar
0      abc
1   2  abc
2   3  abc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder you can put a temporary file into, you can create a csv file and reread it with your new separator:

```
df.to_csv('yourfolder/yourfile.csv',index = False)

df = pd.read_csv('yourfolder/yourfile.csv',sep = '. ')
```